# Is possible to make a library jpa based?

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I'm looking to create some projects with common classes for every other project I create, web or standard.

In eclipse I'd already created two projects with the maven quickstart archetype without the jpa facet, but with the eclipselink libraries in the maven POM to anotate entities and jpa stuff. One project is for generic JPA access and another project for security (user entities, user services, user repository) that uses the JPA access project.

Then I create a 3rd project with the same archetype from last 2 project for testing the previous 2, but this have the JPA facet and the Persistence.xml. When I try to do something JPA related, it says the metamodel is empty. Then I found on the internet and the documentation says I have to use the  tag in my persistence.xml, but I dont know how since Im including the previous two project in the build path of eclipse, not exactly any jar file. How can I achieve this?

Excuse my english translation.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need an [Composite Peristence Unit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite). Also, it will probably require some care in your built/deployment scripts.

Comment: Does it work on non full EE containers or java SE apps?

Comment: Is useful info,but not exactly what I'm looking for since I'm using same database and same persistence unit.